# Play Animation with specefic Time [iPhone Animation]

Tags: iphone

iam trying play animation with xcode,in specefic Time for example after 3 minutes play an animation .. i don't know how coding with NSTimer !

here is my animation codes :

```
     NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage1.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage2.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage3.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage4.gif"], nil];

     UIImageView *myAnimatedView = [UIImageView alloc]; 
[myAnimatedView initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
 myAnimatedView.animationImages = myImages;
 myAnimatedView.animationDuration = 0.25;
 myAnimatedView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[myAnimatedView startAnimating];
 [self addSubview:myAnimatedView]; [myAnimatedView release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned you don't know how to use `NSTimer`, now would be a good time to learn.

Read the documentation for `NSTimer` and look at the sample apps that use it.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out ! :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(myAction) userInfo:nil repeats:FALSE];
```